# Error executing matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I have a script that creates png images from log data. It works fine on a production machine, but now spits errors on a new box while processing this line:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20,14))


AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'subplots'
```

I suspect issues in version differences in various modules. Any insights?

Comment: I'm assuming you've imported matplotlib as plt?

Comment: What versions of python/mpl are you running? How is `plt` imported in your code?

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: IPython.__version__: '0.13.2', matplotlib.__version__: '0.99.1.1', seems the production box has a newer version of matplotlib. I will install the new version on the nex box and see if that resolves.

Comment: Thanks folks, installing the latest matplotlib seems to solve the issue.

Comment: @nom-mon-ir, it might be best to write that as an answer to the question and mark it as accepted. (At least so that such an old question doesn't show up as an unanswered one).

Comment: Thanks I just did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version of Ipython does not have this issue. Putting it as answer as suggested by @Jay Bosamiya to make this question closed.